# How to parse Json response in Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hi i am beginner in ionic with angular app development and using below code for Http calls and i got response in json format, Now i want show response **title** in list,I tried lot but not getting result can some one help me please

### Api url:

https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=2&sort=hot

### home.ts:

```
this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=2&sort=hot',{ observe:'response'}).subscribe( res => { console.log(res) ;
          var info=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
          this.countries = info.data.children;
      });
```

### home.html:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let c of countries">
    <h2>{{c.title}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Did you check the ionic documentation before asking? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong key to fetch value in HTML part, the code should be -

```
<h2>{{c.data.title}}</h2>
```

instead of

```
<h2>{{c.title}}</h2>
```

also why are you using `parse` then `stringify` , just simply assign value using `json()` like this -

```
this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=2&sort=hot', {observe:'response'}).subscribe( res => { 
      console.log(res) ;
      let response = res.body;
      this.countries = response.data.children;
    });
```

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nxufvv?file=app%2Fapp.html)

## Update

If you are using `httpClient`  then no need to use `json()` also remove `{observe:'response'}` as there is no need of this in your use case.

Comment: this.countries = res.data && res.data.children; line giving error --> data does not exist in HttpResponse<object>

Comment: Try to console it before assigning to the variable

Comment: your seen my response in api Url?,i want to show title in list but your answer showing me errors

Comment: please try to elaborate your code because i am begginer

Comment: @AbhiRam Check my updated answer with working example

Comment: property json() not find, have to import any dependencies?

Comment: No , you don't need to import anything special for this. check working example in my answer

Comment: No by using this code you will get response in JSON format without any status code, Check again answer , you will get status cide and data as well

Comment: I Hope everything is working and clear now to you, if so please upvote and mark it as accepted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173386/discussion-between-abhiram-and-pardeep-jain).

Answer (score 0):

Use rxmap

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

this.http.post('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=2&sort=hot',{ observe:'response'}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data.data);
});
```

Comment: That's a post request, the question asks for a get request

Comment: this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=2&sort=hot',{ observe:'response'}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data.data);
});

Comment: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
this.http.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/top/.json?limit=2&sort=hot',{ observe:'response'}).subscribe( res => { console.log(res) ;          
      this.countries = info['data'].children;
  });
```